# When doing Android Development where can I find a list all the valid XML attributes for <Button>?

Tags: android

When doing Android Development where can I find a list all the valid XML attributes for the Button element?

I have tried looking at the schema http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android, but that is just a place holder of some kind because nothing exists at the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) lists the documented XML attributes. There are not specifically for Button, just those inherited from TextView (and View). If you go by the sources, you may find an attribute that appears to be supported, but if it's undocumented, the support could go away in a future version of the OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can find them [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html). Expand 'Inherited XML Attributes'.

Answer (score 0):

If using eclipse, one simple approach is to start creating a button in the xml file:

```
<Button
    android:id="myButton" >
</Button>
```

Next, you can start typing another attribute. First type "android", then wait for a couple of seconds:

```
<Button
    android:id="myButton"
    android >
</Button>
```

After you wait, type a colon:

```
<Button
    android:id="myButton" 
    android: >
</Button>
```

After this point, the IDE should popup a window displaying a list of all the options, which you can select to read the javadocs for the selected item.